Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index is out of range
First time posting here. I'm trying to write a program that allows you to delete a student and add a new one, and so forth. But when I delete and I add it again, and then I delete it again, I get this error

Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index is out of range

Here's the code - Students.cs:
namespace StudentsSelector
{
    public static class StudentsList
    {
        public static string[] AllStudents { get; private set; }
        private static int studentCount;

        // New property for assigned roles
        public static Dictionary<string, string> AssignedRoles { get; set; }

        // Static constructor to initialize arrays
        static StudentsList()
        {
            AssignedRoles = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            AllStudents = new string[]
            {
                // List of initial students
                "Alex Jose Rodriguez Taveras",
                "Amaury Daniel Romero Gonzalez",
                "Ashlee Ramirez Rosario",
                "Cyd Marie Jorge Chapman",
                "Edison Yadir Rossis",
                "Edwin Oscar Perez Rodriguez",
                "Eli Samuel Suero Rodriguez",
                "Erickson David Encarnacion Encarnacion",
                "Eudy Yunior Lorenzo Ramirez",
                "Jamil Guzman Feliz",
                "Joan Manuel Arroyo Valerio",
                "Jose Miguel Canela Santos",
                "Maria Del Carmen Diaz Campanas",
                "Maria Marlene Abreu Saiz",
                "Marlon Miguel Vargas Mendez",
                "Michael Dmeshell Sanchez Heredia",
                "Odana Margarita Calderon Pache",
                "Oscar Daniel Tuletta Mercedes",
                "Rafael Antonio Urbaez Hernandez",
                "Smith Morillo Encarnacion",
                "Teudy Joshua Encarnacion Fulgencio",
                "Xander Ruddy Cruz De La Rosa",
                "Yadianna Vargas Pimentel",
                "Yafreisy Emelin Alvarez Capellan",
                "Yoelmi Alexander Alcala Valdez"
            };

            studentCount = AllStudents.Length;
        }

        // Method to reset all students (for testing or initialization)
        public static void ResetAllStudents()
        {
            AllStudents = new string[]
            {
                // Reset the list of students
                "Alex Jose Rodriguez Taveras",
                "Amaury Daniel Romero Gonzalez",
                "Ashlee Ramirez Rosario",
                "Cyd Marie Jorge Chapman",
                "Edison Yadir Rossis",
                "Edwin Oscar Perez Rodriguez",
                "Eli Samuel Suero Rodriguez",
                "Erickson David Encarnacion Encarnacion",
                "Eudy Yunior Lorenzo Ramirez",
                "Jamil Guzman Feliz",
                "Joan Manuel Arroyo Valerio",
                "Jose Miguel Canela Santos",
                "Maria Del Carmen Diaz Campanas",
                "Maria Marlene Abreu Saiz",
                "Marlon Miguel Vargas Mendez",
                "Michael Dmeshell Sanchez Heredia",
                "Odana Margarita Calderon Pache",
                "Oscar Daniel Tuletta Mercedes",
                "Rafael Antonio Urbaez Hernandez",
                "Smith Morillo Encarnacion",
                "Teudy Joshua Encarnacion Fulgencio",
                "Xander Ruddy Cruz De La Rosa",
                "Yadianna Vargas Pimentel",
                "Yafreisy Emelin Alvarez Capellan",
                "Yoelmi Alexander Alcala Valdez"
            };

            studentCount = AllStudents.Length;
        }

        public static void ResizeArray()
        {
            // Create a new array with the increased size
            string[] newArray = new string[AllStudents.Length + 1];
            Array.Copy(AllStudents, newArray, AllStudents.Length);
            AllStudents = newArray;
        }

        // Method to remove a student at a specific index
        public static void RemoveStudentAt(int index)
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= studentCount)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Index is out of range.");
            }

            for (int i = index; i < studentCount - 1; i++)
            {
                AllStudents[i] = AllStudents[i + 1];
            }

            AllStudents[studentCount - 1] = string.Empty;
            studentCount--;
        }

        // Method to get the current student count
        public static int GetStudentCount()
        {
            return studentCount;
        }
    }
}

DeleteStudent.cs:
namespace StudentsSelector
{
    class GetRidStudents
    {
        public static void DeleteStudents()
        {
            string[] Students = StudentsList.AllStudents;

            Console.Write("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante a eliminar: ");
            string? UserSelection = Console.ReadLine();

            if (UserSelection != null)
            {
                bool studentDeleted = false;

                for (int i = 0; i < Students.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Students[i]) && Students[i].IndexOf(UserSelection, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                    {
                        StudentsList.RemoveStudentAt(i);
                        studentDeleted = true;
                        i--;
                    }
                }

                if (studentDeleted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Lista de estudiantes actualizada:");
                    foreach (string student in StudentsList.AllStudents)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(student)) // Mostrar solo los nombres válidos
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(student);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No se encontraron estudiantes que coincidan con la entrada.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("La entrada fue nula. Por favor, ingrese una parte válida del nombre del estudiante.");
            }
        }
    }
}

If someone can help me please do! I've been paying much attention here, thanks and have a blessed day.
I tried rewriting the code, adding more methods to check the index and so on, didn't work. I also tried GPT, nothing worked

You have an iterator from 0 to the current length of the list, but in the middle of the loop you remove an item from the list (so it's now 1 shorter) but the loop is still going to count up to the original length of the list and hence error on the last iteration.

If you're only deleting a single entry you could break out of the loop when you find it, but there should be a method that allows you to simply delete a value directly (i.e. without finding and using the index)

Thank you stuartd & David it works now!

@JoshuaEncarnacion You said when i delete and i add it again and then i delete it again . How do you do the add?

Besides that, try to keep it DRY. Extract the original AllStudents array and copy the array every time you need to (re)set AllStudents.
